# force paste as a plain text not html in primefaces p:editor

Tags: javascript, primefaces, editor, paste

I have p:editor in system and I want to force paste as a plain text not html
I searched alot and I found many solution but nothing work.

for example I tried this solution and it paste nothing in the editor
I think my main problem is with
 `document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);`
Because it insert nothing to the primefaces editor.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {



                $("iframe").contents().bind('paste', function (e) {

                    e.preventDefault();
                    var text = '';
                    if (e.clipboardData || e.originalEvent.clipboardData) {
                        text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
                    } else if (window.clipboardData) {
                        text = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
                    }

                    if (document.queryCommandSupported('insertText')) {
                        document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);

                    } else {
                        document.execCommand('paste', false, text);
                    }


                });


            });
```

Comment: Please any help its very urgent issue.

Comment: Please I want help please:(